# Shape key value 1.0 doesn't match mesh in edit?

Tags: animation, edit-mode, shape-keys, vertex-groups

first time posting, but I can't find the solution anywhere, perhaps not wording it right. It is probably something simple but I've yet to encounter this issue despite having made a number of characters and animations.

I made a mesh for a dog, setting up various shape keys for blinking, opening the mouth, etc. Now when I go to the manipulate the shape keys' values (Ex: Value 0.0 = mouth closed, Value 1.0 = mouth open) even with the value set to 1.0 the mouth only opens about 30% of the way. The vertex group for that shape key looks fine in edit mode but for some reason the mesh won't go further than around 30% when the value is set to 1.0. This is true for all the shape keys associated with this object.

What really bugs me is that this mesh is a copy of an original mesh in the same instance and the original's shape keys work just fine. I know I can increase the max range for the Shape key, but that does not solve the problem. Using Blender 2.93.1

Anyone encounter this issue or have suggestion?
[image]

Comment: What are the values of the "mouth" vertex group?  Take a look at the group in weight paint mode.

Comment: THAT was it, thank you.  The weight value was quite low, blue. Setting it to max, red, put things where they needed to be. Never been an issue before. Thank you again Nathan.